# How to save a string from "click to copy" to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What im tryring to do is copy an email from an email generator and paste is somewhere else, but i cant copy the email into the variable in the first place. i tried

`let email = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="mail_address"]')).getText()` but it didnt work

```
(async function example() {
      let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build()
      driver.manage().window().maximize()
      try {
        await driver.get('https://10minutemail.com')
        //here i should save into a variable
        let email = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="copy_address"]')).click()
        await driver.switchTo().newWindow('tab');
        await driver.get('https://cloud.google.com/')    
        let searchbox = await driver.findElement(By.name('q'))
        //paste it into the searchbox
        await searchbox.sendKeys(email)
    }
    
      finally {
        // await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```

it seems like it doesnt copy into a variable, help me

Comment: let email = await driver.findElement(By.id('mail_address'));
let emailText = await email.getText();

Answer (score 0):

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
(async function example() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build()
    driver.manage().window().maximize()
    try {
      await driver.get('https://10minutemail.com')
      await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="mail_address"]'))))
      await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="copy_address"]')).click()
      
      await driver.switchTo().newWindow('tab');
      await driver.get('https://google.com/')

      let searchbox = await driver.findElement(By.name('q'))
      await searchbox.sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, 'v'))
  }
  
    finally {
      // await driver.quit();
}
})();
```